# Do all churches celebrate communion in the same order (bread-first, wine-second)?

Tags: communion

So, originally, I was going to ask, why do Anglicans serve the bread first, then the wine.  The answer, however, is that it really seems to be the order in Scripture, for as 1 Corinthians 11 says:

> 23 For I received from the Lord what I also passed on to you: The Lord Jesus, on the night he was betrayed, took bread, 24 and when he had given thanks, he broke it and said, “This is my body, which is for you; do this in remembrance of me.” 25 In the same way, after supper he took the cup, saying, “This cup is the new covenant in my blood; do this, whenever you drink it, in remembrance of me.” 26 For whenever you eat this bread and drink this cup, you proclaim the Lord’s death until he comes.

Thus, it is bread, then wine.  Still, I keep thinking that way back in my Baptist days (its been 5 years now!) it was the other way - wine first, then bread.

The question then is two-fold:

1. Are there any traditions that tend to go wine first (if so, which?) and, if that's the case
2. Why?

Comment: Catholics, I believe, take bread dipped in wine, so that would be "simultaneous".

Comment: That's continction - which is a different question.  The elements are still presented in terms of bread first, then wine- but that is a good practical reason...

Comment: Oh... I didn't know that was a real word... figured it was a typo... lol

Comment: My anecdote, not an answer: Every church I have attended did bread then wine; even the churches with a "non-traditional" communion process.

Comment: Not continction. *Intinction*.

Comment: Another anecdote - my church has bread and wine (well, grape juice - we're in a Methodist building!) available for people to help themselves. If things get busy it's not unusual for people to take the wine first if they can't get to the bread, purely for practical reasons.

Comment: @Narian that is not universal. Back when I was RC, they were separate. For several years it was wafer only.

Comment: I asked a priest about intinction and with a stern look and equally stern voice he told me, "When Jesus broke the bread and said the blessing he also said 'When you EAT this bread...' he did NOT say when you DIP this bread!"

Comment: Hey, Dan.  Welcome to the forum.  This is an interesting comment, but it really is not an answer.  When you get some reputation, you'll be able to add comments.

Comment: What about the "Washing of feet"? Is it not done in the churches? I thought that communion consisted of washing of feet, eating of bread and drinking of wine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appear that you have technically answered your own question by reminiscing to your Baptist days when you received wine first and then bread, so no, not all churches celebrate communion in the same order.

I think a deeper question would be whether any churches establish as doctrine the order of the elements. I am not aware of any that do, but there is always a chance that a group on the fringes has elevated this issue above others.

I think more likely if any churches have an official position on the order of the element it's most likely to establish consistency in the order of liturgy, rather than for some doctrinal reason. In general, most churches receive either the elements simultaneously or bread first, wine second to follow the order of 1 Cor 11. Since it is most natural to read this passage during liturgy, it is most natural to receive the elements in this order.

Answer (score 1):

The Body of Christ first. Then the Blood of Christ.  It is his BLOOD freely given up that
He Christ gave. We are saved by his Blood sacrifice. As in Jewish law! The Blood!
Fr. Goad Tucson AZ

Comment: Welcome to the site Fr. Goad. This site unlike others sites is not a forum but a question and answer site. We prefer fact based proofs in answers in order to avoid confusion and opinions. Hope you will stick around.

Answer (score 0):

If this was a Passover seder, then the wine would have been FIRST, as is evident in Luke.  Always the blessing of the wine is first, THEN the blessing of the bread.  To me, it is but one more way the church has attempted to avoid "anything Jewish", and distance itself from the original setting of this event.  In our home group, when we do communion, it is done in the order found in LUKE.

Comment: Welcome! We're glad you are here, but this answer would be much stronger if you explained further – what type of church is your home group associated with, for example?  Is this common practice in your church/denomination more generally?  I hope you'll take a minute to review [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576), and better understand how [your answer can be supported](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/21576).

Answer (score 0):

> The cup of blessing which we bless, is it not the communion of the blood of Christ? The bread which we break, is it not the communion of the body of Christ? (1 Corinthians 10:16)

The order of the bread and wine is not of the greatest importance - and in the quotation above Paul reverses the way it is normally done.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on asking and answering questions.