# Washing of feet - Is it a part of Communion?

Tags: communion

I am asking this with reference to [this question about communion](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/12430/do-all-churches-celebrate-communion-in-the-same-order-bread-first-wine-second).

1. Does any church practice the "Washing of feet" ceremony before the "eating of bread and drinking of wine"?
2. If no, what is the justification given for this?

I am looking for biblical reasons why this is not done (if that is the case, as the linked question seemed to indicate)

Comment: One major one - logistics/time.

Comment: So the answer is: Because of inconvenience, we don't do it even though Jesus at His last meal found time to do it? Give a biblical answer. If there is no biblical reason then state that as answer.

Comment: Jesus was doing it for twelve people, with no time constraints.

Comment: I don't understand what you are getting at?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Washing of feet - Is it a part of Communion?**

There are some denominations that practice foot washing as an ordinance. I have heard of some that practice it separate from communion and others that include it with communion.

In the Bible it is a recorded event at the same time as the last supper.

There is speculation that the argument recorded in Luke among the disciples about who was going to be the greatest in the Kingdom was taking place as Jesus began to wash the feet of the disciples (recorded in John). This cannot be specifically proven, but it would fit with a clear answer to the disciples contentions.

To understand foot washing and why is was a necessary job and assigned to the lowest person in the household, one has to appreciate that without motor transport, goods are transported by donkey. The donkey leaves an accumulating reminder of his presence in the streets. Places with infrequent rainfall can accumulate a lot of reminders. If you wear sandals, you will find that you also accumulate reminders.

Jesus tells his disciples that they should do likewise for each other.

> John 13:14-15  If I then, your Lord and Master, have washed your feet;
>   ye also ought to wash one another's feet.  For I have given you an
>   example, that ye should do as I have done to you.

Some have taken these words as the establishment of a ritual ordinance. Some of those have included this ordinance with communion. Others take this as a general admonition towards a willingness to do even the lowest task for our brothers and sisters in Christ.